# Strange behavior OpenCL using Union inside Register

Tags: ubuntu, union, opencl

Im getting a strange behavior using variable union(private) in opencl. The code:

```
v = { 0, 1, 2, ... } // Defined in host and load to Device

typedef union svec8{
    int  word[8];
    int8 word8;
} vec8;

__kernel
void red( global vec8 *v, global int *out ){
    uint sizeBin = 8;
    vec8 binning = {0}; // Every Thread has a 8-space bin, initialized with 0
    uint gID     = get_global_id(0);
    int temp;

    binning.word8 = v[ dID ].word8;

    #ifdef CONDITION
        temp = 0;
        for ( uint i = 0; i < sizeBin; i++ ){
            temp += binning.word[ i ];
        }
    #endif

    if ( dID == 0 ){
        *out = binning.word[n]; // n belongs to [0, 7]
    }
}
```

The problem is that, for every n that a choose, when CONDITION is defined, *out is always equal 1, but if i undef CONDITION, *out gets the right value, i.e., 0,1,.., or 7, of course depending which n i choose.

I also noted that if i stop uing union and just use int8, it solves the problem.

Thanks in advance,

Platform: Ubuntu 12.04 - 3.2.0-24-generic-pae - Driver OpenCL 1.2 AMD-APP (923.1)

Comment: Can people (whoever it was) explain downvotes of the question?

Comment: I think somebody does not like me! lol

Answer (score 3):

AMD has bugs with union alignment, might that be the cause? See [my report](http://devgurus.amd.com/thread/158559). I suggest that you try running the same code with Intel SDK, to see if it makes a difference.

**EDIT:** In my own code (many different unions), I use this solution, until it gets fixed upstream:

```
#define AMD_UNION_ALIGN_BUG_WORKAROUND() __attribute__((aligned(32)))
//            this is the biggest alignment value in the union ^^^^^
// in your case sizeof(int)*8=32 (in bytes)

// define unions like this
union svec8 { /*...*/ } AMD_UNION_ALIGN_BUG_WORKAROUND() vec8;
```

Comment: First you could also swap the `int` and `int8` (aligned/unaligned) parts in the struct.

Comment: You are right, that works! But after solving that, i found another problem. I've changed the lines: 

       `temp = 0;
        for ( uint i = 0; i < sizeBin; i++ ){
            temp += binning.word[ i ];
        }`
to
        `for ( uint i = 1; i < sizeBin; i++ ){
            binning.word[ 0 ] += binning.word[ i ];
        }`
 And checked the binning.word[n] value, and this gives 0 for n = 0...7 respectivly

Comment: In `in your case sizeof(int)*8=32 (in bits)` don't you think thats in bytes and not bits?

Comment: Yes, you're right, it is in bytes actually. I had 128 in code and thought it gotta be in bits then, but it is not (for double16). I edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: And for the other problem, could it be related to memory is stored/saved? Why should `binning.word[n]` change for `n>0`? I would only expect `[0]` to be the sum.

Comment: I don't understand, cause i get the values from 0 to 7 using: `binning.word8 = v[ dID ].word8;` so binning.word[0] should be 0, binning.word[1] should be 1 and so on until binning.word[7] = 7, at least for thread 0. After this i use a for to sum from 0 to 7 and put the sum in `binning.word[ 0 ]`, i.e., `for ( uint i = 1; i < sizeBin; i++ ){ binning.word[ 0 ] += binning.word[ i ]; }`. Shouldn't work?

Comment: I am not sure, read the standard what memory consistency is guaranteed; you're however breaking anti-aliasing (which is supposed in OpenCL IIRC). Well, also be prepared for the fact that OpenCL implementation are not very standard-conforming (best experience with Intel, AMD is buggy but reponsive, nVidia is buggy and doesn't care).